# Colorbox overlay not hiding all the content on page

Tags: colorbox

My colorbox overlay is not hiding all the content on page. The images on the page are displaying on top of the overlay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".iframe").colorbox({
         iframe:true, 
         width:"840px", 
         height:"620px",
         scrolling: false
   });
});
```

Comment: Read the answer from @Jack below. Consider revising your question to provide a lot more of your specific context, else the community is reduced to guessing. Not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Is it images, or is it flash? Have you edited the colorbox.css document?  What is the z-index of your images & parent elements? If it's flash, have you set the wmode to transparent?

Nobody can help you with this because the question is completely specific to your current markup and css, which you have shared none of.